# Vuejs dynamic value name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have multiple select option with custom naming and i wish to push those custom names to back-end but it doesn't get the name.

## Code

`sample`

```
<select @change="zoneChange('city', $event)"></select>
<select @change="zoneChange('area', $event)"></select>
<select @change="zoneChange('link', $event)"></select>
```

What I want to get in backend is like:

```
array:1 [
  "city" => 4
]
```

or

```
array:1 [
  "area" => 1
]

array:1 [
  "link" => 5
]
```

so that way i can filter my database result based on input name `city, area, link, etc.` and find related data to those ids `4, 1, 5....`

**Currently what i get is:**

```
array:1 [
  "val" => 4
]
```

> I need that `val` changes to my custom names.

`Script`

```
zoneChange(val, e) {
    // val = city, area, link, etc.
    // e = 4, 1, 5, etc.
    console.log(val, e)

    axios.post('/api/admin/maps/valChanger', {val: e})
    .then(res => {
        //.....
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //.....
    });
},
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: You want `{ [val]: e }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use array syntax `[]` to set object key dynamically:

```js
zoneChange(val, e) {
  axios.post('/api/admin/maps/valChanger', {[val]: e})
    .then(res => {

    })
}
```

In javascript, when you set objects keys like shown below, the word `key` is interpreted as a string:

```
console.log({ key: 'value' })
// will output {key: "value"}
```

And if you want to set some value as a key, you have to use that `[]` array syntax:

```
// the value of the variable will be used as key
let key = 'someKeyName' 

console.log({ [key]: 'value' })
// will output { someKeyName: "value" }
```